# How to use derived types in node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I'm using Node Soap https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap to send SOAP requests and parse the answers.

Now I've got a service which has a derived type `<searchedAddress xsi:type="PersonAddressDescription">`.

***How do I specify the `xsi:type="PersonAddressDescription"` in my request?***

**This is what I do**

```
  const args = {
    searchedAddress: {
      location: {
        street: 'Karl-Theorstraße 88',
        zip: '34234',
        city: 'Rummelshausen'
      },
      firstName: 'Foo',
      lastName: 'Bar'
    }
  }

soap.createClient(WSDL, wsdlOptions, (err, client) => {
  client.getReport(args, (err, result) => {
    if (err !== null) {
      console.log(client.lastRequest)
      reject(err)
    }
    resolve(result)
  })
})
```

**This is how the request is supposed to look like:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Header/>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <getReportRequest xmlns="http://www.service.com/superservice/v1.00">
      <searchedAddress xsi:type="PersonAddressDescription">
        <location>
          <street>Karl-Theorstraße 88</street>
          <zip>34234</zip>
          <city>Rummelshausen</city>
        </location>
        <firstName>Foo</firstName>
        <lastName>Bar</lastName>
      </searchedAddress>
    </getReportRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `attributes` to the node you are requesting. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122566/node-soap-how-to-create-a-complex-message-with-specific-attributes)

```
 const args = {
    searchedAddress: {
      attributes: {
        'xsi:type': 'PersonAddressDescription'
        },
      location: {
        street: 'Karl-Theorstraße 88',
        zip: '34234',
        city: 'Rummelshausen'
      },
      firstName: 'Foo',
      lastName: 'Bar'
    }
  }
```

Comment: This was the solution. Sorry that I missed awarding the bounty. I was not able to check out your solution in time.